# deal with many members datas from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array and the createtime is already sorted by AES.

```
$list = array(0 => array('createtime' => 90,'message'=>'ad','user'=>'a'),
        1 => array('createtime' => 91,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'b'),
        2 => array('createtime' => 93,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'b'),
        3 => array('createtime' => 93,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'c'),
        4 => array('createtime' => 94,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'d'),
        5 => array('createtime' => 99,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'a'),
        6 => array('createtime' => 100,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'a'));

As you can see,maybe the array is from a sql table,what I want is to deal with these data,the result of array like this.

$list = array(0 => array('createtime' => 90,'message'=>'ad','user'=>'a'),
        1 => array('createtime' => 91,'message'=>'ae+ae','user'=>'b'),  
        2 => array('createtime' => 93,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'c'),
        3 => array('createtime' => 94,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'d'),
        4 => array('createtime' => 99,'message'=>'ah+ah','user'=>'a'));
```

Yeah, you may find the createtime between 5 and the same user data combined.What I want is just like this,and in the future it may includes more users and more createtimes.
And I coded like this to deal with it,but it worked not well when I change my datas like add user or change user and so on.

```
 $diff = 0;
 $count = 0;
 $d = array();
 $j = array();
 for($i = 1;isset($list[$i]);){
 if ($list[$i]['user'] != $list[$i-1-$count]['user']) {
     if (!in_array($list[$i]['user'], $d)) {
    $d[$diff] = $list[$i]['user'];
    $j[$diff] = $i;
    $count++;
    $diff++;
    $i++;
    continue;
    } else {
    $i++;
    $count++;
    continue;
    }
   }
   if($list[$i]['createtime'] - $list[$i-1-$count]['createtime'] < 5){
  $list[$i-1-$count]['message'] = $list[$i-1-$count]['message'].'<br>'.$list[$i]['message'];
  array_splice($list,$i,1);
   } else if ($count == 0) {
  $i++;
   } else {
 $i = $j[0] + 1;
 $count = 0;
 $diff = 0;
 $d = array();
 $j = array();
   }
 }
```

It seems to have something wrong.So how should I do to meet my requirements.And more users between short createtime should also be considered.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're after something like this?

```
$list = array(0 => array('createtime' => 90,'message'=>'ad','user'=>'a'),
        1 => array('createtime' => 91,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'b'),
        2 => array('createtime' => 93,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'b'),
        3 => array('createtime' => 93,'message'=>'ae','user'=>'c'),
        4 => array('createtime' => 94,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'d'),
        5 => array('createtime' => 99,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'a'),
        6 => array('createtime' => 100,'message'=>'ah','user'=>'a'));

$out = array();

$prevUser = 0;
foreach($list as $key => $value){
    if($value['user'] === $prevUser){
        echo $value['user'], $prevUser, '<br>';
        end($out);
        $k = key($out);
        $out[$k]['message'] .= $value['message'];
        continue;
    }
    $out[] = $value;
    $prevUser = $value['user'];

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Nope,I also want to compare the createtime that the same user's next data createtime is in 5...

Comment: So what would happen if user `a` had a message at `91`, `92`, and `97`? Would it include `97` or would that be left out? Because it is not within five of `91` but it is of `92`